# Angularjs select with additional option

Tags: angularjs

I have a multiple select that is connectted to the model. I would like to add an additional option that's not part of the model and handle the click event. Is that possible and how?

```
    Language:
    <select multiple name="Language_Custom" 
        ng-model="model.Language_Custom" 
        ng-required="true" 
        ng-options="pn.Value as pn.Label for pn in Language_Custom_PossibleValues">    
    </select>
```

Comment: No it's not. And even if it was, it's probably a bad UX choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that returns a copy of your `Language_Custom_PossibleValues` array and appends your additional option to it.  This lets you add an option without changing the underlying model.

```
$scope.getLanguages = function(){
    var languages = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.Language_Custom_PossibleValues, function(item){
      languages.push(item);
    });
    languages.push({Value: 0, Label: 'Extra Option'});
    return languages;
}
```

Now use that function as the source in the `ng-options`:

```
Language:<select multiple name="Language_Custom" 
   ng-model="model.Language_Custom" 
   ng-required="true" 
   ng-options="pn.Value as pn.Label for pn in getLanguages()"
   ng-change="changeLanguage()"></select>
```

You also need a `changeLanguage` function that is called when the selected item in the list changes:

```
$scope.changeLanguage = function(){
    if($scope.model.Language_Custom.indexOf(0) > -1)
      alert('do somthing here');
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4oh1I5H96EokrRqBU8La?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I used:

```
<div>
    Language:<select multiple name="Language_Custom" ng-model="model.Language_Custom" ng-required="true">
        <option ng-click="selectAllMultiValues(model, 'Language_Custom', Language_Custom_PossibleValues)">Select All</option>
        <option ng-repeat="pn in Language_Custom_PossibleValues" ng-model="p.Value">{{pn.Label}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```